# Sentence to AST structures?

Tags: syntax-trees, information-structure

How can we distinguish the meaning from POS,words,form..or any other information.. f.e.

```
 the cube is **in** the box

 the sign splits a rule **in** two parts
```

in the first case the meaning is **containment** in the second it is just sort of connector.

the reason I want to know this is to build structures. If i want to use **in** as functor :

```
   in(cube,box)
   in(sign-split-rule,two-parts)  <-- not convincing

   split(sign,rule^in(rule,two-parts))  <--- better
```

i.e. in the first case i can use **in** , in the second i have to prioritize the **verb** first..

Is it the case always to use verb first and only then to look for connectors like in,into,on,after,before ...

BTW I'm not looking for pure Linguistic rules, but more for a Structural/relational rules.
verbs,nouns reveal L-Struct, connectors reveal R-Struct

---

this is my initial crack on it, for now POS-based :

```
import spacy

class Sent2Struct(object):

    def root(self,doc):
        for word in doc :
            if word.dep_ == 'ROOT' : return word

    def lol(self,root) :
        if len(list(root.children)) == 0 : return root.text
        childs = [ self.lol(child) for child in root.children ]
        return [root.text] + childs 



   In [100]: print( ss.lol(ss.root(nlp('the box is on the table'))) )                                                                                                           
   ['is', ['box', 'the'], ['on', ['table', 'the']]]
```

i.e.

```
   is(box(the), on(table(the)) )
```

Comment: This is a complex topic and there are many competing theories of (lexical) semantics. If FOL is good enough for you I’d recommend Jerry Hobbs’ “The syntax of English in an abductive framework”, he discusses this kind of problems.

Comment: Your edit is just a recursive linearisation of the dependency tree. It’s not POS-based (you aren’t using any tags aside from ROOT which is a technicality for the base case), it’s based on lemmata. Note that it’s still syntax, not semantics.

Comment: u right, i know its still just syntax ;(..